# SalesForce marketing System not getting decrypted in Using java Crypto

Tags: salesforce-communities

I need some help in understanding, how to decrypt SalesforceMarketingCloud encrypted String into java.
I should admit that I have few things missing in my questions but this is what ever I have been provided so far

Algorithm – AES256, 256 Bit
Initilization vector – 16 bytes
Salt – 8 Bytes
Passphrase – “presharedpassphrase123”

As per my understanding the Input String has been encrypted using 
EncryptSymmetric(@Clear, "AES", @null, @Passphrase, @null, @Salt, @null, @IV)

But when I try to decrypt it at Java side, it fails for various reason.

My best shot has been getting a garbage String as output so far when I used combination like below

NoPadding, CBS, and hashing my passphrase(which is 22 char long) to 32 bit using SHA-256

Can anyone please help, any Java code sample which you successfully used in past.

```
private String decryptWithKey(String myKey, byte[] strToDecrypt) throws Exception
{
    MessageDigest sha = null;
    try {
        key = myKey.getBytes(CHAR_SCHEME);
        sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

        key = sha.digest(key);
        key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 32); 
        secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, ALGO);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");

        byte[] ivByte = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];


        ivByte = hexStringToByteArray("0716A494177F29F102AF33AFD0253BA1");;

        System.out.println(new String(ivByte));
```

//          IvParameterSpec ivParamsSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV);
          IvParameterSpec ivParamsSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivByte);

```
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivParamsSpec);
          setDecryptedString(new String(cipher.doFinal(strToDecrypt)));



      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {

          System.out.println("Error while decrypting: "+e.toString());

          throw e;
      }
      return decryptedString;

}
```

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?